Why php_value doesn't work in httpd.conf?
I'm migrating from Apache 2.4.6/PHP 7.4 to Apache 2.4.57/PHP 8.2
Everything seems to be working ok, EXCEPT the php flags in my Apache conf are no longer acceptable.  I moved from mod_php to php-fpm.
Is there a different syntax for adding php.ini variables inside apache configurations?
like:
php_admin_value engine 1
php_flag display_errors 1
php_admin_value file_uploads 1
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /www/tmp-www
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 3M

Apache will no longer start with these commands in any config file.
I can't find any documentation on how to accomplish the same things via php-fpm in an httpd.conf?
Any help.   Is there a different syntax or restriction?

Apache configuration files and directives are used for Apache and Apache modules. The php_... directives are defined by mod_php. If you are not using it any more, the directives are no longer available. The php-fpm module defines other directives, but none are to change INI settings.


I can't find any documentation on how to accomplish the same things
via php-fpm in an httpd.conf?

When you use php-fpm, you can not embed PHP directives in Apache configuration files because PHP and Apache are now completely separated. I.e., PHP no longer has any idea that Apache even exists.
Instead, you have to use php-fpm configuration file.
Alternatively, you can use PHP ini file (global or per-dir) and/or ini_set() within your source. Depending on your distro, the PHP package may be set up to include all *.ini files in a certain directory, so you might be able to just add a small my.ini file with just the directives you want to change. You can inspect the output of phpinfo() (as seen from a paged served by php-fpm, and not the cli) to see what files it is sourcing.
